# Error running expo build:ios on Windows Computer for React Native App

Tags: ios, node.js, react-native, expo

I am attempting to build an IOS version of my React Native App using Expo CLI, but I get the following error:

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KoPmT.png)

Has anyone encountered this issue before?  The Android version of my app built fine and my app runs smoothly, so I am having trouble interpreting why this issue is occurring.  I should also note that I am enrolled in Apple's Developer Program, so I don't think that's the issue.  Any advice would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you want build iOS app then you need Mac machine. Without Mac machine you can't build iOS app.

Answer (score 0):

The Apple SDK is not available on windows and only available on mac, for that reason you cannot build Apple apps , “even if it’s on react native” on windows.